# Conditional inside search result excerpt

Tags: tags

I'm trying - and failing - to add a conditional tag to the excerpts in my search results... so that if the excerpt is from a post it displays the post date and permalink, whereas if the excerpt is from a page it only displays the permalink and not the date.

Displaying the appropriate meta info is straightforward, but it's the conditional code that I'm struggling with, having experimented with various permutations of if (is_single()), if (is_page()), and echo I'm lost among the curly brackets, semi-colons, quotes and what-nots.

Help appreciated. Please/thanks/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are making typical mistake between [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) which tell you which kind of page are you on (search in your case) and functions which tell you data of the current post in the loop.

What you want in this case is probably [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) and make your output conditional on result of it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're inside the loop.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php if ( get_post_type() == 'page' ) : ?>
    <?php /* well, this is a page */ ?>
  <?php else : ?>
    <?php /* any other post_type like post, attachment other CTP */ ?> 
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Like Rarst suggested you can write conditions for any other specific post type using `get_post_type()` and add additional `else if ( 'my_cpt' === get_post_type() ) {}`s before the final `else {}`.

Comment: @gulliver Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), then take appropriate action on this question and all your other question with answers ;-)